# Where does Preview store PDF annotations on OS X Lion?

Tags: pdf, osx-lion

I'm working on a tool in Python to extract highlighted passages from PDF files.  I regularly highlight PDFs in Preview on OS X Lion but haven't found a good tool to extract these passages.  Other apps exist that do allow you to highlight and export such as Skim but I figure there has to be a way to extract the ones I add in Preview.

I figured that the highlights would be stored in the HFS+ extended attributes for the PDF file but after looking at them using xattr it seems that they're stored elsewhere.  I also looked at PDFKit but I only saw how to create annotations rather than locate them.

If someone could tell me where to find the highlights/annotations or point me at some documentation that explains this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Technically speaking, highlighting parts of a PDF is adding an *annotation* to the file. These annotations are PDF objects defined in the PDF specification. They are stored inside the PDF file itself, i.e. they do modify the original file! That's why you'll not find a trace of the highlights in the HFS+ extended attributes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using PDFKit you can get annotation from any PDFPage instance.

`[myPDFPage annotations]` will return an array of annotations for that particular page.

See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzFramework/Classes/PDFPage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003875) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, highlighting parts of a PDF is adding an annotation to the file. These annotations are PDF objects defined in the PDF specification. They are stored inside the PDF file itself, i.e. they do modify the original file! That's why you'll not find a trace of the highlights in the HFS+ extended attributes...

So the answer to the question of your title line is: **Preview stores the highlights inside the PDF file as fully compliant PDF objects.**

The answer to your real question implied in your text (*'I want to extract the highlighted passages'*) was well answered by sosborn.